# Format Multiple EditTexts with StringBuilder rather than copying code multiple times

Tags: java, android

I am attempting an Email Application.

I have a stringbuilder method that is able to highlight and underline text in an `EditText` when the user goes to the next `EditText`, like in the screenshot below:

[image: Format Text with StringBuilder]

The problem is, to do the above, I have had to copy and paste the code numerous times to do this. This is the code:

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((EditText) v).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {

            /* Below highlights the email addresses after the user has entered them and moved on*/
            SpannableStringBuilder emailFormat = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            String emailFormatted = edittext.getText().toString();
            SpannableString formattedString= new SpannableString(emailFormatted); 
            formattedString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(238,233,233)), 0, emailFormatted.length(), 0);
            formattedString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, emailFormatted.length(), 0);

            emailFormat.append(formattedString);

            edittext.setText(emailFormat, BufferType.SPANNABLE);

            }

        }
    });
```

I repeat the code four times as shown below (by renaming `edittext` as `edittext2` and `edittext3` and so  on).

```
edittext2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                ((EditText) v).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {

            /* Below highlights the email addresses after the user has entered them and moved on*/
            SpannableStringBuilder emailFormat = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            String emailFormatted = edittext2.getText().toString();
            SpannableString formattedString= new SpannableString(emailFormatted); 
            formattedString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(238,233,233)), 0, emailFormatted.length(), 0);
            formattedString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, emailFormatted.length(), 0);


            emailFormat.append(formattedString);

            edittext2.setText(emailFormat, BufferType.SPANNABLE);

            }

        }
    });
```

The edittexts are declared in the `onCreate` method as shown below:

```
edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);   // From
edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);  // To
edittext3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); //  cc
edittext4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); //  bcc
```

How could I do this with less code, by reading in all the `EditText` in one block of code?

### SOLUTION:

As suggested by @Commonwares, I created a new class `Foo` that implements `OnFocusChangeListener`:

```
class Foo implements OnFocusChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        v = (EditText) v;
        if (hasFocus) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            ((EditText) v).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {

            /* Below highlights the email addresses after the user has entered them and moved on*/
            SpannableStringBuilder emailFormat = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            String emailFormatted = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
            SpannableString formattedString= new SpannableString(emailFormatted); 
            formattedString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(238,233,233)), 0, emailFormatted.length(), 0);
            formattedString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, emailFormatted.length(), 0);

            emailFormat.append(formattedString);

            ((EditText) v).setText(emailFormat, BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        }

    }

}
```

Then I can implement it in the `onCreate` method like this:

```
Foo test = new Foo();

edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(test);
edittext2.setOnFocusChangeListener(test);
edittext3.setOnFocusChangeListener(test);
edittext4.setOnFocusChangeListener(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I do this with less code

Use one listener inner class rather than four.

Each time you do `new OnFocusChangeListener()` you are creating a *separate* class with *separate* code. Instead, create one such class (`class Foo implements OnFocusChangeListener`) with one `onFocusChange()` method. The widget that you need to work with is passed in as the `View v` parameter to `onFocusChange()` -- just cast that to be an `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare - I have attempted this, please see my edited update, there are no errors when I declare this class, but I am not sure how to work with it, any further tips appreciated :)

Comment: @Tom: "I am not sure how to work with it" -- the same way you work with any other Java class. Instead of `new OnFocusChangeListener()` and have all of the code duplication, use `new Foo()`. Or, better yet, have a single instance of `Foo` and assign the same `Foo` instance to each of the `EditText` widgets.

Comment: got it working - thanks. Learning Java as I go. Updated my solution - CommonsWare,  what you think of it in terms of efficiency? (at least compared to the original method!)

Comment: @Tom: If by "efficiency" you mean "runtime efficiency", your changes had no effect.